# UICollectionView - Scroll out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an UICollectionView let's say 200 width. I can scroll vertically without any problems. But I would like to be able to scroll the collectionView 60 px out of bounds to the right. Is this possible?

Comment: If you're using UICollectionViewFlowLayout, setting itemSize.width > 200, it will be scrollable.

Comment: Well, I use my FlowLayout to do some other work for me. Im not sure I can combine it. I was thinking subclassing the CollectionView and override hitTest.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is, `UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, that means that you can add an inset. This means that you will scroll more but the content size where you place your cell will be the same.

> SWIFT
>  `var contentInset: UIEdgeInsets`
>  OBJECTIVE-C
>   `@property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets contentInse`t 
> Use this property to add to the
>   scrolling area around the content. The unit of size is points. The
>   default value is UIEdgeInsetsZero.

Remember also to add a `scrollIndicatorInsets` to balance the scroll bar movement.